# footer won't fill 100% width of page

Tags: html, css, width, footer

This is my footer styled as shown below, but it does not fill the full width of the page. I tried changing the width property to max-width, but it didn't solve the issue. I noticed that I can still scroll across my page, which shouldn't be the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
.footer {
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 150px;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #ffe7e8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position` property to your CSS code and `padding` property to give your footer some spacing.

```
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #ffe7e8;
}
```

Comment: Hi Julia, apologies for the late reply, I decided to go on a last min holiday with family right in the middle of my project! :-). Recently got and working project now. I figured out it was the background images in my other components that were causing the issue. All fixed now. I was pushing the image to much to the left and therefore causing the scrolling.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score -1):

I tested it myself and got the same.

I believe most browsers apply default padding and margin to the <body> tag.

To remove the padding/margin applied by default, try the following in your css file:

```
body {
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
  }
```

That resolved it for me anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Bryan, apologies for the late reply, I decided to go on a last min holiday with family right in the middle of my project! :-). Recently got and working project now. I figured out it was the background images in my other components that were causing the issue. All fixed now. I was pushing the image to much to the left and therefore causing the scrolling. 

Thank you :-)

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;`

This will get rid of the scrolling bars for that element.

Comment: Hi Shira, apologies for the late reply, I decided to go on a last min holiday with family right in the middle of my project! :-). Recently got and working project now. I figured out it was the background images in my other components that were causing the issue. All fixed now. I was pushing the image to much to the left and therefore causing the scrolling. 

Thank you :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding **position:fixed** and **right:0** to your code. Also Remove **width:100%** That shall help.

```
.footer{
   position:fixed;
   margin:0;
   margin-top:150px;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   background-color:#ffe7e8;
}
```

This code works fine with me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Forest Fire 7, apologies for the late reply, I decided to go on a last min holiday with family right in the middle of my project! :-). Recently got and working project now. I figured out it was the background images in my other components that were causing the issue. All fixed now. I was pushing the image to much to the left and therefore causing the scrolling. 

Thank you :-)